# How to conceive the difference between $l_1$ and $l_\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

The $l_1$ space is composed of sequences that converge, and that can be real or complex, with the norm $||x||=\sum |x(n)|$.
The $l_\infty$ space is also composed of converging sequences, real or complex, however with the norm $||x||_\infty=sup_j|x(t)|$.

So is the norm the only difference, while the elements in each space are identical?
Are there other differences between these two spaces, and how  can these be best illustrated?

Thanks

Comment: $l^\infty$ is the space of *bounded* sequences (supplied with the norm you wrote).

Comment: No, $\ \ell_\infty\ $ is the set of *bounded* sequences.  It contains *non-converging* sequences such as $\ (-1,1,-1,\dots,(-1)^n,\dots)\ $, which are not in $\ \ell_1\ $. Thus $\ \ell_1\subsetneq\ell_\infty\ $.

Comment: bounded sequences. if you represent sin as power series, and you have an infinite number of its sequence terms,  what is the example of  bounded seq of the power series of sin? and what is the meaning of having such a bounded sequence?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera. You should have $\ell_{\infty}\not\subseteq \ell_1$. I think you made a typo.

Comment: The space $\ell^1$ is separable while $\ell^\infty$ is not separable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet While it's true that $\ \ell_\infty\not\subseteq\ell_1\ $, I don't consider $\ \subsetneq\ $ and $\ \not\subseteq\ $ to be synonyms. In my vocabulary $\ \ell_1\subsetneq\ell_\infty\ $ says that $\ \ell_1\ $ is a strict subset of $\ \ell_\infty\ $, which is a stronger statement than $\ \ell_\infty\not\subseteq\ell_1\ $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making a confusion with $l_1$ and $l_\infty$ definitions.

Formally,

$$ l_1 = \Big\{ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb R\colon \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n| < \infty\Big\}.$$
If you want to describe $l_1$ in other words, this represents the set of absolutely summable sequences (in the sense that the series associated with every sequence in $l_1$ must be absolutely convergent).

On the other hand, $\mathbf{l_\infty}$ **is not the set of absolutely summable sequences.** Formally,

$$ l_\infty = \Big\{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb R\colon \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} |x_n| < \infty   \Big\}.$$
Again, if you want to describe $l_\infty$ in other words, this would be the set of all **bounded** sequences.

There are differences between $l_1$ and $l_\infty.$ For example, consider the sequence $(\,(-1)^n\,)_{n \in \mathbb N}:$ this sequence is obviously bounded (above by $1$ and below by $-1$), but the sum of its terms (in absolute value) isn't finite. Thus, this sequence belongs to $l_\infty$ but doesn't belong to $l_1$ (as a consequence, it follows that $l_\infty$ is not contained in $l_1$). This is the main difference between such sets.

As you "pointed", this two sets can also be seen as normed spaces, with the norms you mentioned, but I believe your confusion urged mainly from the definitions.

Comment: thx.what is then an  example of a functional that sends a sequence from $l_1$ to $l_infty$?

Comment: I say I am not sure what do you mean by a "functional" that sends $l_1$ to $l_\infty$ because normally the term "functional" is used for mappings from normed spaces **to** the field of scalars.

Comment: $l_1$ is not the set of convergent sequences. Look $x_n = 1/n$. It's the set of absolutely summable sequences. That's a way of saying it "in other words". You could also say it represents "a set of convergent sequences" as opposed to "the set of convergent sequences".

Comment: @DionelJaime Thanks for your headsup. I have updated my answer accordingly - can you give it a second check?

Comment: @Rodrigo How do you then call an integral that acts on an $l_1$ element and gives a $l_\infty$ element then?An operator?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Yes, operator would be an appropriate term for such a mapping.

Comment: Muchas gracias!